# Overriding socket.io's emit and on?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

During development, it helps me greatly to be able to see what packets arrive and gets sent. This is possible on the server side with logger. On the client end, however, there is no logger. I find myself to be littering console.log all over the place.

Is it possible to override socket.emit and socket.on with console.log(arguments)? If I can override this at the before my socket, it would be really elegant.

Somebody advised me to override the Parser instead.

What's your 2cents on this?

**EDIT**

I tried Kato's suggestion and wrote the following:

```
var _origEmit = socket.emit;
socket.emit = function() { 
  console.log("SENT", Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  _origEmit.call(socket, arguments);
};
```

This works. However, Not so much with socket.on. My strategy is to wrap each callback with a console.log. If you know python, it's kind of like putting function decorators on the callbacks that console.log the arguments.

```
(function(socket) { 
var _origOn = socket.on;
socket.on = function() { 
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    , handlerType = args[0]
    , originalCallback = args[1];

  var wrappedCallback = function() { 
    // replace original callback with a function 
    // wrapped around by console.log
    console.log("RECEIVED", Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    originalCallback.call(socket, arguments);
  }

  _origOn.call(socket, [handlerType, wrappedCallback]);
}
```

Any one can point to why monkey patching socket.on is not working?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To override **socket.on** you actually need to override **socket.$emit**.

Following example works both client and server-side (tested on socket.io 0.9.0):

```
(function() {
  var emit = socket.emit;
  socket.emit = function() {
    console.log('***','emit', Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    emit.apply(socket, arguments);
  };
  var $emit = socket.$emit;
  socket.$emit = function() {
    console.log('***','on',Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    $emit.apply(socket, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code to create a default listener function and a catch all event function: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405070/socket-io-client-respond-to-all-events-with-one-handler/19121009#19121009)

Comment: I simply replaced `socket.on`, and it worked, socket.io 0.9.16

Comment: Too bad we need to change the way socket.io works to achieve this. Seems to me it's a much desired functionality.

Comment: Lino Silva you can turn on debug by introducing localStorage.debug = '*' into javascript. It will turn on socket io debug and show all performed operations.

Answer (score 5):

Works, tested:

```
var _emit = socket.emit;
    _onevent = socket.onevent;

    socket.emit = function () { //Override outgoing
        //Do your logic here
        console.log('***', 'emit', arguments);
        _emit.apply(socket, arguments);
    };

    socket.onevent = function (packet) { //Override incoming
        var args = packet.data || [];
        //Do your logic here
        console.log('***', 'onevent', packet);
        _onevent.call(socket, packet);
    };
```

Comment: This works but make sure not to use this: `var packet = packet.data;` inside the function, doing so makes the packet "invalid" and the call function won't be invoked.

Answer (score 4):

There is a module called [socket.io-wildcard](https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard) which allows using wildcards on client and server side, no need to overwrite anything anymore

```
var io         = require('socket.io')();
var middleware = require('socketio-wildcard')();

io.use(middleware);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('*', function(){ /* … */ });
});

io.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {

      var _origEmit = socket.emit;
      socket.emit = function() {
         console.log(arguments);
         _origEmit.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
      };


  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, you need to use slice. You also need to use `_origEmit.apply` instead of `call`.

Comment: Right on; I'm apply/call dyslexic apparently; I'm thinking about putting those two and php's strpos/in_array on a Post-It next to my monitor :)

Comment: Updated with @clarkf's comments

Comment: `_origEmit` not `origEmit` :P