# Running code from Socket.io notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io, eval

I'm running a NodeJS server which is sending notifications to the clients when `somebody` does `something`, for example, when a client deletes a row from a grid, Socket.io informs the rest of the clients that a row got deleted.

In that example, I could add something like `actionType: rowdeleted` to the socket.io message and then just detect the `actionType` on the client side and refresh the grid. Anyways, the problem is that there can be infinite number of actions (and new ones can be added), so I can't code a function for each action type on the client side.

Then I thought maybe I can send some code via socket.io and make the client run it, but I'm not sure if that is the best way for doing what I want. Also, how are the clients going to run that code? Via `eval`?

I'm open to any suggestion :)

Comment: please be more clear on what you are trying to code.

Comment: the clients are going to run code via functions, when the server emits a event, its a js function, you can write anything their which will get executed. In easier term nodejs server will execute a js function on client side. please refer to any socket+node example to get clear understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered something similar, but not as eval.  You clearly must have the code to execute somewhere, be it on the server side.  Why not create a way to let the client know what script/code/action to get and execute it.

I have used something similar out of a similar need.  The action type referenced a script in a specific path on my server (/js/actions/ACTION.js).  Upon getting the command to run the action, the client would check if it has the action, if not, it would go get the action. After that it would run the action on the script.  RequireJS is good for this kind of thing.  It will keep track of what actions you have and what actions you don't have.  It will also make sure to get the action if it doesn't have it before it run some function that needs it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but how exactly is the code run once it gets downloaded from the server? I'm guessing it's not via eval.

Comment: It adds the scripts to the DOM in the `<head>` with the src attribute being the path on your server.  It more or less ensures that the script is coming from you can not something that someone injected.  RequireJS handles that plus it will run the code after the script is downloaded and executed.

Comment: Ok then, I guess I'll use that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is evil (c)

> so I can't code a function for each action type on the client side.

there's no point emiting events from server if they wont be handled on the client(s)

have a client handle funcion for each type of event your server is emiting.
Otherwise bind on [all events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405070/socket-io-client-respond-to-all-events-with-one-handler) and handle then

Comment: The problem is, like I said, new actions can be added at any moment, meaning that the client maybe won't have those new functions (as the project is single-page based). That's why I need some way to pass code/commands from the server and let the clients run that code/commands (instead of relying that the client already has the code/commands).