# socket.io: client receive all incoming messages into a single function

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io 1.2.0 .  In a client browser how to receive all events in a single listener

```
socket.on("*",fuction(event,data){ 

});
```

My previous implementation is not working after i uploaded from 0.9 ....

my previous hack for receive all events

```
     var original_$emit = getSocket().$emit;

        getSocket().$emit = function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            original_$emit.apply(getSocket(), ["*"].concat(args));
            if (!original_$emit.apply(getSocket(), arguments)) {
                original_$emit.apply(getSocket(), ["default"].concat(args))
            }
        };
```

Comment: I think it's duplicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405070/socket-io-client-respond-to-all-events-with-one-handler . A solution: override `socket.on` and `socket.emit`.

Comment: @creeper $emit is not available in 1.2.0; In that page all they gave result for 0.9...

Answer (score -1):

This is not a perfect solution but its working fine....

Code changes **server socket.io**

/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js

In line no: 128

```
 if (~exports.events.indexOf(ev)) {
    emit.apply(this, arguments);
 }
```

change to

```
if (~exports.events.indexOf(ev)) {
   var arg = ["*",arguments];
   emit.apply(this, arg);
}
```

In line no: 328

```
emit.apply(this, args);
```

change to

```
args.splice(0, 0, "*");
emit.apply(this, args);
```

Example:

```
 var io = require('socket.io')(SERVER);
     io.on('connection', function (socket) {
         socket.on('*', function (event, data) {
         });
    });
```

---

Code changes socket.io for (**browser javascript to node.js app**);

node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js

In line no: 724

```
emit.apply(this, arg);
```

change to

```
var arg = ["*",ev];
emit.apply(this, arg);
```

In line no: 847

```
 if (this.connected) {
     emit.apply(this, args);
 }
```

change to

```
 if (this.connected) {
    args.splice(0, 0, "*");
    emit.apply(this, args);
 }

var arg = ["*",ev];
```

Example:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on("*", function (event, data) {
});
```

---

code changes for require('**socket.io-client**') (node.js app to node.js app);

/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js

In line no: 129

```
emit.apply(this, arguments);
```

change to

```
var arg = ["*",ev];
emit.apply(this, arg);
```

In line no: 253

```
 if (this.connected) {
     emit.apply(this, args);
 }
```

change to

```
 if (this.connected) {
    args.splice(0, 0, "*");
    emit.apply(this, args);
 }

var arg = ["*",ev];
```

Example:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io(URL,{});
socket.on("*", function (event, data) { });
```

---