# Socket.on() listen for any event

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to catch when any event, regardless of the name was sent from a socket. Is there some sort of wildcard I can use here for that?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('any event', function (data) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket.io Client: respond to all events with one handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405070/socket-io-client-respond-to-all-events-with-one-handler)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the wildcard plugin to listen to all events

http://socket.io/docs/faq/
https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard

Answer (score 2):

u can use

```
socket.onAny((eventName, args...)=>{
//something
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/#socketonanylistener