# Is there a function to intercept all socket.io data from the server on clientside

Tags: node.js, socket.io

socket.io clientside code can use this

```
  var socket = io('http://localhost:8888');
socket.on('news', function (data) {

    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

but i want to intercept all data from the server emitted by socket.io not only news and then process the data. is that possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to register for all events emitted by "socket". 
This issue was widely discussed [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/434). It's a no go in the socket.io code, but commenters suggest some ways to do it.

Your best bet is probably to follow [this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832414/overriding-socket-ios-emit-and-on/8838225) :

```
(function() {
 var emit = socket.emit;
 socket.emit = function() {
 console.log('***','emit', Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    emit.apply(socket, arguments);
};
var $emit = socket.$emit;
socket.$emit = function() {
    console.log('***','on',Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    $emit.apply(socket, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Please look at the linked topic for more informations.

You may find additional informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405070/socket-io-client-respond-to-all-events-with-one-handler) on some other ways to do it..

Comment: this doesnt work for me. the clientside socket.io.js has a function which  gives access exactly what i want    //Socket.prototype.onPacket = function (packet) {}; but how to acces the function.

Comment: i use socket.io.js 1.1.0 from [link]https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client. i hasnt the function socket.$emit as in older versions.