# socket.io-client wildcard support?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to get wildcards to work on the client as well?

Example:

```
var connection = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');

connection.on("*", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

There's topics regarding this already, but they don't seem to work with the latest version of the client (1.4.7)

**EDIT:**

The current implementations https://stackoverflow.com/a/33960032/1372517 works, Reason it didn't work for me is because I'm using Electron + Angular and the angular implementation of socket.io prevented me from doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9674248/3103677 http://stackoverflow.com/a/10405187/3103677 May be helpful.

Comment: Already looked at these and tested, none which worked with the latest version.

Comment: @Makkesk8 What is the use case?

Comment: Oh I really screwed up, Seems like the culprit was the angular socket.io plugin, it's working just fine right now.

@BLewis Angular + electron